# Rust winapi GetLastInputInfo not detecting correctly

Tags: winapi, rust

I am VERY new to rust, and really programming in general. I am writing a rust program that will detect idle and print out the time since the last input. I am using the winapi crate. The code below returns between 0ns and 31ms, regardless of how long it's been since I pressed a key or moved the mouse. It never gets higher than 31ms.

```
use winapi::um::{
    winuser::{
        LASTINPUTINFO,
        PLASTINPUTINFO,
        GetLastInputInfo
    },
};

fn sleep(milliseconds: u64){
    let mills = std::time::Duration::from_millis(milliseconds);
    std::thread::sleep(mills);
}

fn main() {
    loop {
        let now = unsafe { winapi::um::sysinfoapi::GetTickCount() };
        let mut last_input_info = LASTINPUTINFO {
            cbSize: std::mem::size_of::<LASTINPUTINFO>() as u32,
            dwTime: 0
        };

        let p_last_input_info: PLASTINPUTINFO = &mut last_input_info as *mut LASTINPUTINFO;

        let ok = unsafe { GetLastInputInfo(p_last_input_info) } != 0;

        let logvar = match ok {
            true => {
                let millis = now - last_input_info.dwTime;
                Ok(std::time::Duration::from_millis(millis as u64))
            },
            false => Err(format!("GetLastInputInfo failed"))
        }.unwrap();

        println!("{:?}", logvar);
        sleep(1000);
    };
}
```

I considered that it might be some program that is keeping the PC from going idle, so using powercfg -requests, I found some audio streams open (still don't know how to fix that). I just don't know if that could be what's happening here. Community expertise requested!

Comment: That does smell like some sort of "utility" that prevents the machine from going idle.  Powercfg is not going to show it.  Consider using Task Manager, Details tab and killing off processes one by one.

Comment: Taking your suggestion, I went through and killed anything that looked like it might have that function. I was leary to just go down the line, because I didn't want to close any system processes that would cause instability. Needless to say, none of the processes I killed solved the problem. Is there any way to see what is sending input into Windows?

Comment: I tried an API Monitor from http://www.rohitab.com.  I had many programs and services to go through, so it got really tedious, but I couldn't find any keyboard or mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

It might be good for inspecting problem to execute cpp code below. It works well on my PC.

- If it work well           --> Your Rust code or Rust winapi problem
- If it does not work well  --> Your PC problem

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    LASTINPUTINFO   lii;
    lii.cbSize = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);

    for (;;) {
        int ret = GetLastInputInfo(&lii);
        printf("ret=%d diff=%d\n", ret, GetTickCount() - lii.dwTime);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

output in my PC with mouse move and stop

```
ret=1 diff=578
ret=1 diff=1578
ret=1 diff=2594
ret=1 diff=0
ret=1 diff=422
ret=1 diff=1422
ret=1 diff=2422
ret=1 diff=3438
ret=1 diff=4438
ret=1 diff=5438
ret=1 diff=79
ret=1 diff=16
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  After the adventure of learning how to compile and run C++ code (again, new to programming), it turns out that your C++ code returned the same numbers I was getting from my rust code, so it is definitely something that is resetting idle count.  I still have no idea how to find out what.

Comment: hahaha, i recommend to start program after disconnecting your mouse.

Comment: Tested... no change.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the culprit.  It was not the rust code at all, but my Game Controller Driver that was registering as input. For some reason, whenever I have a game controller connected, it does that. It took me forever to figure it out, and even so happen to just stumble onto the answer after weeks of googling. Consider this question closed.